# VBScript Launch Default Mail Window

Tags: asp-classic, vbscript, email

Just wondering if it is at all possible in classic ASP/VBScript to launch a new window of the default mail client.

I have tried the following:

```
set objOutlk = createobject("Outlook.Application")
set objMail = objOutlk.createitem(olMailItem)
```

But got nothing but an error: ActiveX cannot create object: Outlook.Application.

Any advice is much appreciated.

Rob.

Comment: Just to be sure: You are trying to run a VBScript on a client machine or a ASP-Classic server-side script?

Comment: Sorry, it's asp server side. But if necessary can this be done client-side?

Comment: The should be to open a mail window on client machine and pre-populate with some data and then allow the client to send a mail so that it is tracked through their exchange

Comment: Well if it's server side, how should this run on the client? Maybe your just looking for the `mailto:` hyperlink?

Comment: Would client-side work the way it is intended?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to provide a simple way to open the default mail client message of a user viewing your (asp) page just add a `mailto:` hyperlink:

```
<a href="mailto:You@acme.com?subject=Hello%20World&body=Hi%20there">Send Msg</a>
```

The `mailto:` will trigger the browser to open the default (or configured) mail client.

You can append a query string defining the subject line and the mail body - in my example the subject is *"Hello World"* and the body text is *"Hi there"*.

Notice the blanks are **url-encoded** to `%20`

Comment: Cheers Filburt. I may try this as well but I think the answer I found below is what I am after unless you can see anything wrong with the JS?

Comment: If you also need to gather some of the data for sending the mail from your users, building the link using JS is the way to go - basically you'll end up with a similar `href` value like my static example.

Answer (score 0):

After a little thought (thanks to some of you guys for the prompt) it made sense to run this client side and I used the following JScript:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">

 function send() {
 alert("clicked")
     var recpt = "info@example.ccTLD"
     var subj = "FASTER BETTER SOONER: Look at Monash Rowville rail now"
     var text = "<Enter your name and address here> %0D%0DMelbourne is growing and more people need transport. With concern about climate change and rising petrol prices, Melbourne's growth is not sustainable without more and better public transport.%0D%0DVictorians want more people catching public transport, cycling and walking; fewer trucks on our roads, more freight on rail; and fewer kilometres travelled by car and truck.%0D%0DPublic transport should: be fast, frequent, reliable, affordable and safe; grow as Melbourne grows; be available to all Melbournians; and be managed as an integrated, co-ordinated network.%0D%0DThis means bringing forward existing public transport projects, committing to new projects and accelerating programs to move freight off our roads and onto rail.%0D%0DIt also means looking very closely at the impact on greenhouse gas emissions of any new transport projects like tunnels and freeways.%0D%0DWe especially urge you to look at a feasibility study for a Monash Rowville rail line. %0D%0DAs Melbourne's population grows, better public transport will both reduce traffic congestion and provide a much needed antidote to spiralling petrol prices. "
     var bcc = "people@example.ccTLD"
     var content = new Array()

     content[0] = "mailto:"
     content[1] = recpt
     content[2] = "?subject="
     content[3] = subj
     content[4] = "&body="
     content[5] = text
     content[6] = "&bcc="
     content[7] = bcc
     content = content.join("")
     window.location = content
 }
```

This seems to the results I expected.

Rob